# Wordpress wp clone site formatting is missing after local server to bluehost migration

Tags: wordpress, migration, clone, restore, bluehost

Problem after migrating from localhost server to bluehost using wp clone (successful restore).

[image: wp site on local server]

and below is the hosted website.
http://wp.perfec.com/

As you can see only the header and footer is showing. Everything in between seems to be missing.
I can see all my images in the media library but none of them are showing.
The database seems to have been migrated correctly (all tables are there) and I ran a search and replace for my localhost url and none was found in the database.
Site title is there "Scuti Web Design"
Something to note is that I'm using a child theme (Optimizer-child), no customization has been done, but even if I switch to the original Optimizer theme everything is still pretty much blank.
Hopefully someone can give me a pointer of what had gone wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works wonderful! I simply followed this guide http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/guide-to-migrating-localhost-wordpress-to-live-site/ Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer for you to accept. I'm glad I was able to help. Thanks @Louie Cheung

Answer (score 0):

I use a plugin called 'duplicator' and haven't had a failed move yet. wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator give her a go and see if the results are the same.